# Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag

Tags: soap, anypoint-studio, mule-component, mule4, mule-connector

I am using web service consumer(1.6.9) in Mule4 and triggering the external soap service, the external service is returning SOAP FAULT and below is the SOAP fault which I am getting as below

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>Internal Server Error</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unexpected close tag 
            </urn:UniqueName>; expected
        </urn:UniqueNam>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [40,54]
    </faultstring>
    <Detail>Invalid incoming request /Buyer/soap/C133/X-T/testPull?null</Detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but Web service consumer in mule is returning the below error:

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag()
```

Please let me know what is the issue, it seems web service consumer is throwing the above error while parsing the above soap fault.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be complaining that the SOAP fault response is not valid XML because of this line:

```
        </urn:UniqueNam>
   at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [40,54]...
</faultstring>
```

Note how the text is between `</urn:UniqueNam>` and `</faultstring>`. That's not valid in XML. There should be an XML tag or nothing there instead of plain text.

Comment: In the above SOAP fault the detail tag contains special characters like colon, apostrophe, curly braces because of which Web service consume is unable to parse it, I think target system need to send that Content in CDATA so that our web service consumer will not parse it and try to read it as is, then this error may not occur, please let me know whether my analysis is correct or do you want to add anything.

Comment: That could be another problem but it is not the problem mentioned in the error message. The problem seems to be that string `at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [40,54]` is between two end tags, not in between a tag. I'm updating my answer to be more clear.